# sammy.js route generates loop when calling ajax?

Tags: jquery, sammy.js

i have the following sammy.js app which should get a static page, based on the current url.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var app = $.sammy('div.container', function() {

        this.get(/#\/(.*)/, function(context) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/foo/' + this.params['splat'],
                success: function(c) {
                    $('div.wrapper').html(c);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

it actually works and it loads the content of the called url into the div.wrapper element. but  instead of stopping the ajax call after loading it, it keeps running the sammy.js runRoute method. here's the console log:

```
[Sat Jun 30 2012 18:29:40 GMT+0200 (CEST)] div.wrapper runRoute get /#/bar/foo/
[Sat Jun 30 2012 18:29:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)] div.wrapper runRoute get /#/bar/foo/
[Sat Jun 30 2012 18:29:44 GMT+0200 (CEST)] div.wrapper runRoute get /#/bar/foo/
```

any advice on this? thanks!

Comment: What does the code that you are loading via ajax look like?

Comment: @Tronic did you find any solution for this issue?